# Adding "quicklist" actions to apps in the dock

Tags: vala

If i have Noise or Terminal in the dock and right click on the app icon in the dock it presents me with a bunch of options eg. "Open as Root", "About" etc etc. How do i do this for my app?

I'm developing an app for elementary and wanted to add some custom actions for my app so how do i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add at the end of the .desktop file something like

`[Desktop Action Screen]
Name=Take a Screenshot of the Whole Screen
Exec=gnome-screenshot`

See this for more information
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/LauncherAPI#Quicklists